# Unable to generate plots in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Below is my code to generate a Pareto from a data set, based on selected dates by the user.  When I run the app, I am only able to generate the date selection but no graphs. Any ideas why I am not seeing a graph? I want a graph that updates when the date range updates.  Thanks. I assume the code in my ui is fine to output code.  I just can't seem to get the server to output my graph.

```
#load libraries
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#read in data
Rawdata <- read_csv("Rawdata.csv")
#change time from chr to Date
Rawdata$timestamp= as.Date(Rawdata$timestamp, format= "%m/%d/%Y")

#defining a ui
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("COCBRN Pareto"),

dateRangeInput("daterange",
               label="Select the date range",
               start=min(Rawdata$timestamp),
               end=max(Rawdata$timestamp),
               min=min(Rawdata$timestamp),
               max=max(Rawdata$timestamp),
               format="mm/dd/yyyy",
               separator="to"
               ),

               textOutput("startdate"),
               textOutput("enddate"),
               textOutput("range"),
               tableOutput("subdata"),

#this is where I am trying to output the plot
mainPanel(plotOutput("pareto"))

)

#writing the server
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$startdate<-renderText({
    as.character(input$daterange[1])
  })

  output$enddate<-renderText({
    as.character(input$daterange[2])
  })

  output$range<-renderText({
    paste("Selected date range is", input$daterange[1], "to", input$daterange[2])
  })



  #Creating a vector to convert failure codes to text
  srp.codes<-c("Reset"= "00","Blower leakage due to incomplete adhesive joint"="11A", "Uncured adhesive" ="11B", "Motor to fan cover installation incorrect"="11C", "Hood nonconformance cosmetic"="13D", "Retest after first time failure"="13AA", "Hood leak @ unknown location"="13A", "Neckdam holes/tears"="13B", "Blower leakage due to inc adhesive joint"="18B", "Leakage at filter crimp"="18A", "Impeller gap incorrect"="16A", "Blower outlet threads stripped"="13AF", "Uncured adhesive"="18C","NPF at hood"="18V", "Perimeter seal leak"="13P", "Hole in hood (not in seal)"="13E", "Exhaust valve cover missing or installed incorrectly"="13M", "Air flow fails on low side of tolerance"="12LVL", "Low Flow Motor Wires Reversed"= "17A", "No Problem Found (Blower Test)"="12V", "Crimp Nonconformance"="18G")

  #removing a code from my data
  Data_no_00<-subset(Rawdata, code!="00")
  func_year<-as.numberic(format(input$daterange[1],"%Y"))
  func_month<-as.numberic(format(input$daterange[1],"%m"))
  func_days=c(as.numberic(format(input$daterange[1],"%d")):as.numberic(format(input$daterange[2],"%d")))

  #filtering data based on user input
  filt<-
    subset(Data_no_00,test==0& Year==func_year& Month==func_month &Day%in%func_days)%>%
    group_by(code)%>%
    summarise(freq=n())%>%
    arrange(desc(freq))

  #matching failure codes to text
  filt$code<-names(srp.codes)[match(filt$code, srp.codes)]


  plotting<-filt[1:5,]%>%
    mutate(relative_freq=freq/sum(freq), cumulative_freq=cumsum(relative_freq))
  the_order<- plotting$code



    p<-plotting%>%
    ggplot(aes(x=code, weight= relative_freq))+
    geom_bar(width=0.5,fill="blue")+
    scale_x_discrete(limits=the_order)+
    scale_y_continuous(label=scales::percent)+
    geom_point(aes(x=code,y=cumulative_freq))+
    geom_line(aes(x=code,y=cumulative_freq, group=1))+
    labs(x="",y="Relative Frequency", title= "February COCBRN Pareto 2019")+
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=270))


    output$pareto<-renderPlot({p})


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using reactive elements properly. Have you reviewed a Shiny tutorial? I might suggest the videos here as a good overview of how Shiny code works: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/

Comment: I believe that your graph is not showing because the ggplot code is not within the renderPlot() element.

Answer (score 0):

as MrFlick said above, the issue lies in the use of reactive elements. There would be many different ways to implement your code with reactive elements. This would be one:

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$startdate<-renderText({
    as.character(input$daterange[1])
  })

  output$enddate<-renderText({
    as.character(input$daterange[2])
  })

  output$range<-renderText({
    paste("Selected date range is", input$daterange[1], "to", input$daterange[2])
  })



  #Creating a vector to convert failure codes to text
  srp.codes<-c("Reset"= "00","Blower leakage due to incomplete adhesive joint"="11A", "Uncured adhesive" ="11B", "Motor to fan cover installation incorrect"="11C", "Hood nonconformance cosmetic"="13D", "Retest after first time failure"="13AA", "Hood leak @ unknown location"="13A", "Neckdam holes/tears"="13B", "Blower leakage due to inc adhesive joint"="18B", "Leakage at filter crimp"="18A", "Impeller gap incorrect"="16A", "Blower outlet threads stripped"="13AF", "Uncured adhesive"="18C","NPF at hood"="18V", "Perimeter seal leak"="13P", "Hole in hood (not in seal)"="13E", "Exhaust valve cover missing or installed incorrectly"="13M", "Air flow fails on low side of tolerance"="12LVL", "Low Flow Motor Wires Reversed"= "17A", "No Problem Found (Blower Test)"="12V", "Crimp Nonconformance"="18G")

  #removing a code from my data
  Data_no_00<-subset(Rawdata, code!="00")

  #filtering data based on user input
  filt<- reactive({
    func_year<-as.numberic(format(input$daterange[1],"%Y"))
    func_month<- as.numberic(format(input$daterange[1],"%m"))
    func_days <- c(as.numberic(format(input$daterange[1],"%d")):as.numeric(format(input$daterange[2],"%d")))

    df <- subset(Data_no_00,test==0& Year==func_year& Month==func_month &Day%in%func_days)%>%
      group_by(code)%>%
      summarise(freq=n())%>%
      arrange(desc(freq))

    df$code<-names(srp.codes)[match(df$code, srp.codes)]

    df
  })

  output$pareto<-renderPlot({

    #matching failure codes to text
    plotting<-filt()[1:5,]%>%
      mutate(relative_freq=freq/sum(freq), cumulative_freq=cumsum(relative_freq))
    the_order<- plotting$code


    p<-plotting%>%
      ggplot(aes(x=code, weight= relative_freq))+
      geom_bar(width=0.5,fill="blue")+
      scale_x_discrete(limits=the_order)+
      scale_y_continuous(label=scales::percent)+
      geom_point(aes(x=code,y=cumulative_freq))+
      geom_line(aes(x=code,y=cumulative_freq, group=1))+
      labs(x="",y="Relative Frequency", title= "February COCBRN Pareto 2019")+
      theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=270))

    p
  })


}
```

In addition to the webinar MrFlick posted above you can also look at the example in the Shiny gallery that explains reactivity: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactivity.html

Comment: I've written my server as Wil has above except I fixed a typo in the as.numeric function.  I have not changed my ui at all from the original post.  I still can't seem to get a graph output.

Comment: without sample data it will be difficult to troubleshoot further. are any errors thrown when you run the code above?

Comment: No errors are given.  The app runs, I can see and interact with the date selection, but the rest of the screen is blank with no graphs.

Comment: Then you'll need to debug line by line. Choose a start and end date for test purposes, and then run all of the code in the server portion but do it step-by-step interactively in the R console. After each step, check your variables and objects to ensure they are as you expect. My guess would be that either your data processing steps are causing all of your records to be dropped or your plotting code is not creating any visible layers, but without the data I can't tell.